# Show views of parent activity highlighted in the dialog

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, android-dialogfragment, customdialog

Currently, the Fab button down at the bottom is hidden under the shadow(dim) of the dialog window.

I what to make it display on top of the shadow.

The fab button belongs to the parent Activity from where the dialog is getting called.

[image: Here is how it looks]

Comment: this is added using `DialogFragment`? Also, imo this sounds like a bad UX since, the user may not expect this kind of behavior.

Comment: Actually, I am providing this as an example actual implementation is quite different and it was done using DialogFragment. , and I can't post it here because of a few reasons.